# Case Deflection not working in Salesforce Community

Tags: case, knowledge, articles, support

I have set up Knowledge and a community page containing the Contact Support Form and Case Deflection components. However when typing in the form, no articles are suggested.

In the Knowledge Settings I have set Case Subject field to be one of the 'Case Fields Used to Find Suggested Articles' (plus Description which I think is searched by default). My community user can view articles when they are surfaced from the global search bar, so I don't think it's a profile permissions issue.

Can anyone suggest anything else I need to configure to get Case Deflection working?

EDIT: There was a typo originally which said 'no cases are suggested' rather than 'no articles'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that the language of the community (English UK) did not match the language of the Knowledge base (English US).

Changing the languages to be the same made the case deflection component work.

Answer (score 0):

This is as designed, as per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_case_deflection.htm&type=5):

> The Case Deflection component searches text as it’s being entered into the Contact Support Form component, and returns relevant **articles** and **discussions**

[image]